# Is as.matrix in a certain package?

Tags: r, powerbi, lasso-regression

I'm trying to use

```
as.matrix()
```

in an R visualization script in Power BI to convert my dataset into a matrix but I'm getting an error:

```
**Error Message:**

R script error.

Installing package into 'C: /Users/jorda/Library/3.6.1'

(as 'lib' is unspecified)

testing the url 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/glmnet_4.0-2.zip'

Content type 'application / zip' length 2106029 bytes (2.0 MB) downloaded 2.0 MB

Loading required package: Matrix

Loaded glmnet 4.0-2

Warning message:

package 'glmnet' was built under R version 3.6.3

Error in storage.mode (y) <- "double":

   invalid to change the storage mode of a factor

Calls: glmnet -> elnet

**Execution interrupted**
```

I was having the "double" issue in my desktop R software earlier and turning the dataset I'm using into a matrix solved that problem. So now I'm trying to convert my dataset into a matrix in Power BI's R visualization script and it won't work. I have a lot of packages listed in my desktop R script but I'm not sure which one is needed.

Comment: `as.matrix` is in the `base` package that should be loaded by default. If you look at the help page, `?as.matrix`, you can see the package listed at the top left. However, from the snippets you've posted, I don't see how `as.matrix` has to do with your issues...

Comment: It might be possible, you are using this function from other library and therefore you are getting this error. Relaunch your R, and without loading any package then run this command.